# How to reference a filtered array in ng-options

Tags: angularjs

I want to be able to reference the number of items in the `ng-options` after a filter. Is this possible?

For example, this works:

```
<select ng-model="selectedItem"
    ng-options="_item.id as _item.name for _item in PageModel.objects"
    ng-show="PageModel.objects.length>0">
    <option value="">-- Select --</option>
</select>
<span ng-show="PageModel.objects.length==0">No objects to display</span>
```

I can reference the length of the array `PageModel.objects` and use that to turn components on or off.
But how do I do the same for a filtered array?

```
<select ng-model="selectedItem.objectId"
    ng-options="_item.id as _item.name for _item in PageModel.objects  | filter:{type:filterBy}"
    ng-show="PageModel.objects.length>0">
    <option value="">-- Select --</option>
</select>
<span ng-show="PageModel.objects.length==0" >No objects to display</span>
```

This will obviously always return the length of the original array, but is there a way to reference the filtered list as that changes?

This is how I would expect it to work:

```
ng-options="_item.id as _item.name for _item in PageModel.objects  | filter:{type:filterBy} as filteredObjects"
```

And then to be able to use the variable `filteredObjects` like:

```
<span ng-show="filteredObjects.length==0" >No objects to display</span>
```

But this doesn't work.

Here is a fiddle showing the example working. I would like the value (8) to be dynamic.

[fiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/declanmcd/4cfecf76/)
(The buttons are just used to simulate the desired outcome)

I know I could do it using a watch on the model but can it be done in another way similar to above?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should apply the same filter in ng-show too.

```
<select ng-model="selectedItem.objectId"
ng-options="_item.id as _item.name for _item in PageModel.objects  | filter:{type:filterBy}"
ng-show="(PageModel.objects|filter:{type:filterBy}) && (PageModel.objects|filter:{type:filterBy}.length>0">
<option value="">-- Select --</option></select>
```

For a better explanation you can look at this link: http://php.quicoto.com/use-ng-show-filtering-data-angularjs/

Bye

Comment: thanks for the additional info. Both you and PinBack got the same answer at the same time.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
Select from a list of {{(PageModel.objects|filter:{type:filterBy}).length}}: <-- need to be able to reference/use this?
```